# Google App Engine in your domain: what about the URIs (mail, jabber, etc.)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

Reading Google's documentation (http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/domains.html), I understand I can allow users to access my application from my own domain.

I've done that for few NGOs in the past and access like http://mail.[domain]/ is redirected to http://mail.google.com/a/[domain]/.

My questions:

1. Does it mean an access to http://console.[domain]/ will be redirected to http://appengine.google.com/a/[domain]
2. What about the URIs like: [user-id]@[app-name].appspotmail.com (for e-mails) or [app-name]@appspot.com (for IMs)

Answer (score 2):

You will not be redirected and the user will only see your domain except for SSL connections.
There are however an "enterprise" version that also allows SSL.

Same goes for e-mails

Answer (score 1):

Mail and XMPP will still be sent/received through `[app-id].appspotmail.com` and `[app-id].appspotchat.com`, respectively, as far as I know. I believe there is an open issue about this but I wouldn't be surprised if it wasn't a high priority for the App Engine team.

Comment: My application is multi-stream: users can use the Web console, can send e-mails, can chat with the engine, can add it to a wave, etc. I'm looking forward to having everything under my domain umbrella...

I guess I'm going to stay with the regular settings for now.

Thanks,
A+, Dom

Comment: Hey Dom, welcome to SO! If this answers your question, you should accept it by clicking the checkmark under the question's score. Accepting answers tells others with the same question that this is the correct answer, and the more answers you accept, the more likely people will be to answer your questions in the future. It also gives both of us reputation points :) -- See the FAQ about accepting answers: http://stackoverflow.com/faq